# UITableview not updating uitableviewcell custom cell from storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have tried as many as solution I found to resolve this problem.
My latest code is show blow:

```
  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

  [[cell viewWithTag:1000] removeFromSuperview];
      [[cell viewWithTag:2000] removeFromSuperview];

  // other code for setting view that works perfect then 
  if(some condition){
   UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upgrey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.frame=upButton.frame;
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(upButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:btn];
        UIButton *btn2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downgrey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn2.frame=downButton.frame;
        [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(downButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:btn2];
        btn.tag=1000;
        btn2.tag=2000;
   }

  return cell;
```

but this does not work. if i add 
      [[cell viewWithTag:1000] removeFromSuperview];
          [[cell viewWithTag:2000] removeFromSuperview];

in start it remove buttons from all cells. and if i do not use this. it shows all cells with these two buttons.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want these buttons to show up? Your results are exactly what I would expect.

Comment: i want to show these buttons as part of tableview cell if condition is tru. but if i add [[cell viewWithTag:1000] removeFromSuperview]; [[cell viewWithTag:2000] removeFromSuperview]; lines. it do not show buttons in table view.and if i do not add these lines. it shows button in most of the table cells when i scroll up or down

Comment: Right, using`removeFromSuperview` removes the buttons.

Comment: when i use "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" this gets the cell from currently cell in memory. they may have previously added that buttons. then i remove previous buttons and add new one.

Comment: using removeFromSuperview removes previuosly added buttons. but not recently added ones.please se above statements. "usingremoveFromSuperview" is before "addsubview"

Comment: What is `upButton`, its frame might be zero, so you don't see anything.

Comment: unbutton us from storyboard. and its frame is not zero. the actual problem is that each and every row is of tableview is updating except UIButton . i tried it many ways. i put the buttons in uitableviewcell in storyboard and upon condition tried make them hide and show. tried them disable and enable on condition true or false. but no one solution worked for me.

Comment: it may be something with reusability of cell with uibutton. can anyone tell why unbutton only are not updating uitableviewcell? all other elements are working and updating perfect on reload tableview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you've already accepted your own answer, I'll take a moment to explain why you had that issue and how you can better structure your `UITableView`s in the future.

The reason why "it shows all cells with these two buttons" when you don't have those `removeFromSubview` lines is because by implementing `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, you're reusing your cells and the contents thereof. Repeatedly adding the same subview during each call of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` makes the fact that you're reusing the cells completely pointless since you're reusing absolutely nothing within them. So either, don't reuse your cells at all or, better yet since each cell's contents are exactly the same, *do* reuse your cells and *also* reuse those buttons.

There are two good ways to do this. One way to do this is to create a UITableViewCell custom subclass. But since your cells' contents are fairly simple and you say your `else` conditional's already functional, I'll suggest a different way that might be a bit less code-intensive. Here's my suggestion:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Create two identifiers -- one for "some condition" one 
    // for the "other condition"
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier1 = @"cell1";
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier2 = @"cell2";

    if (some condition) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier1];

        // Only add the buttons when cell == nil, i.e. during the first
        // time cell's initialized to hold a UITableViewCell
        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier1]

            UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upgrey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn.frame=upButton.frame;
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(upButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell addSubview:btn];
            UIButton *btn2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downgrey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn2.frame=downButton.frame;
            [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(downButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell addSubview:btn2];
        }

    } else {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier2];

        if (cell == nil) {

            ....
```

Comment: thats a good answer. as i have resolved the problem same i this way. i am making your answer as correct.because you elaborated very beautifully the problem.